# Audio filtering strange issue with MATLAB

Tags: matlab, audio

I'm filternig an audio file with matlab inside a function script which has a function named "filtro_pf" created by me which is a band-pass filter and its outputs are the IIR corresponding coefficients:

```
[b,a] = filtro_pf(Ap,As,fp1,fs1,fp2,fs2,1); //BAND PASS FILTER
b2 = [0.0039,0,-0.0156,0,0.0234,0,-0.0156,0,0.0039];
a2 =[1.0000,-6.2682,17.2660,-27.3421,27.2582,-17.5284,7.0998,-1.6555,0.1701];
wfpf = filter(b,a,audio_stream);
wavplay(wfpf,fs);
```

Note that the second and third lines (b2 and a2) are the values which the function 'filtro_pb()' gives me for those inputs. I've run once and then copied them to these variables. Now, after I run this script, if I ask for 'a' and 'a2' in the console I will have:

```
a =

1.0000   -6.2682   17.2660  -27.3421   27.2582  -17.5284    7.0998   -1.6555    0.1701


a2 =

1.0000   -6.2682   17.2660  -27.3421   27.2582  -17.5284    7.0998   -1.6555    0.1701
```

They are pretty much the same. But if I use 'a2' instead of 'a' in the filter() function, it does not work. I hear a kind of tick sound and that's it. With 'a' I can hear the sound correctly filtered. This same code is used before and it does work:

```
%[b,a] = filtro_pa(Ap,As,fp,fs,1); //HIGH PASS FILTER
b = [0.5411   -1.6232    1.6232   -0.5411];
a = [1.0000   -1.8062    1.2298   -0.2925];
wfpa = filter(b2, a2, audio_stream);
wavplay(wfpa,fs);
```

Again, I used this script previously and saw that these values (from a2 and b2) were the output to these inputs. Now instead of calling the function again (which is commented by the way) I use the 'a' and 'b'vectors directly. It does work for the LowPass and for the HighPass filter.

All of this are for test purposes so I do not expect suggestions like "why use the vector instead of calling the function then?".

I just want to know, how can the function not work with the second variable if they are pretty much the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is more precision present in the variables than is displayed, which means that your `a2` and `b2` vectors are not the same as `a` and `b`.  It might appear surprising that errors on that order would make the filter unstable, but it appears that is what is happening.  You should be able to explore this by looking at the filter response with `freqz`, and by plotting up the resulting audio vector rather than just listening to it.

You can use `format long` to print more precision, but these will *still* have some rounding error.  To avoid, save the vectors to a .mat file and reload that.  The .mat file will use binary format and store the full precision of your vectors.

The reason it works for the other filters is probably because those filters are less sensitive to rounding errors in their coefficients: they have fewer coefficients, and those coefficients are less extreme in value.

Here's a sample comparison of frequency response:

```
[H W] = freqz(b2, a2);  % your filter (with error)
a_error = zeros(size(a2));
a_error(9) = a_error(9)+.001;  % a little bit of error in a single coefficient
[HE WE] = freqz(b2, a2 + a_error);   % frequency response of THAT filter
plot(log10(abs([H HE])))
```

As you can see, a small change makes a large difference.

An actual analysis of the instability comes from looking at the poles and zeros of the filter:

```
[z p k] = tf2zp(b2, a2);
abs(p)
```

If any poles have magnitude greater than 1 (this one does), the filter will be unstable.  Try the real values, then your "approximate" values, and see what happens.

Comment: I've just used vpa(a) to display 'a'with 20 digits and here we go. Now it works. Incredible... once one told me that those filters may be unstable with very little differences but I would never imagine that it was this unstable! Thanks!